# Is $A \cap \{\tau > t\} \in \mathcal{F}_{t}$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Assume $A \in \mathcal{F}_{\tau}$, where $\tau$ is a stopping time. By definition of the $\sigma$-algebra of the stopping time, we know that
$$A \cap \{\tau \leq t \} \in \mathcal{F}_t.$$
**Question:** Is $A \cap \{\tau > t \} \in \mathcal{F}_t$? If it is, how to prove it?

Answer (score 2):

No, this need not be the case.  Let $s < t$ and consider the constant stopping time $\tau = t$.  If $A \in \mathcal F_t$ and $A \not \in \mathcal F_s$, we have $A \cap \{\tau > s\} = A \not \in \mathcal F_s$.

For a less trivial example of why this should not be the case intuitively, consider a Brownian motion $B_t$ and $\tau := \inf\{t \ge 0 : |B_t| = 1\}$.  Then the event $A = \{B_\tau = 1\}$ is in $\mathcal F_\tau$, but $A \cap \{\tau > 0\} = A$ is not in $\mathcal F_0$.